# el valor de un campo se distorsiona a pasar de un archivo txt a dataframe con pandas

Tags: python, pandas

tengo un archivo.txt delimitado por palotes "|". al guardar el archivo en un dataframe un campo cambia de valor o aparece cortado se podría decir.

el valor del campos en el txt es "000008888" al pasar al dataframe cambia a '88888' le cambie .
inicialmente en el dataframe figura como tipo integer lo cambie a object pero sigue igual.

¿como puedo manter el campo con el valor original del archivo.txt
que me figure en el datafram '000008888".

Gracias,

Comment: Bienvenido a la comunidad.
Te sugiero añadir el código relevante para que te puedan ayudar mejor.
Saludos!

Comment: Tal como comenta Barrendeitor, considera agregar el código [editando la pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/616485/edit), incluso una muestra del csv puede ser útil. Especificar que se use `object`/`str` como dtype para esa columna  evita que se interprete como un entero con ceros a la izquierda, la columna no se parseará y  sera una mera cadena (str) de Python dejándola tal como está en el csv, algo debes estar haciendo mal al implementarlo. Por cierto, bienvenido a [es.so], considera mirarte [tour] y [ask] para conocer un poco mejor el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla ;)

Comment: Gracias, me falataba definir la propiedad dtype dentro del read_csv.